# Seleccionar algunas filas de gridview para mostrar en webform2 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Buen dia,

Tengo un gridview al que le inserto data con un datatable el cual funciona perfectamente, se me complica al momento de colocar una fila checkbox para que el usuario pueda seleccionar la fila que quiere para realizar su gestion.
Este es el código del HTML:

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ItemStyle-Width="150px" ID="cbSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="cbSelect_CheckedChanged" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ItemStyle-Width="150px" ID="cbSelected" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="cbSelected_CheckedChanged" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Poliza">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Poliza" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POLIZA") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="RAMO"
                    HeaderText="Ramo" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CERTIF"
                    HeaderText="Certificado" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="NOMRMO"
                    HeaderText="Ramo" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CIA"
                    HeaderText="N. Comp" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="NOMCIA"
                    HeaderText="Compañia" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="RIF"
                    HeaderText="Ident" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CCT"
                    HeaderText="Num" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>`

y en el backend tengo el codigo que llena el gridview y para realizar las validaciones si se ha seleccionado algun checkbox y si esta vacio funciona perfecto

Mi complicacion esta en el boton para transferir las filas seleccionadas a otro webform porque normalmente podria pasar una filla con un "ButtonField" la propiedad "OnSelectedIndexChanged" pero como podria hacer esto con el check box?

tengo esto en el click pero no se como avanzar:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         List<string> test = new List<string>();

         foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in GridView2.Rows)
         {
             if (((CheckBox)gridViewRow.FindControl("cbSelected")).Checked)
             {
                 string ejecutivoId = ((Label)gridViewRow.FindControl("Poliza")).Text;
                 test.Add(ejecutivoId);
             }
         }
         if (test.Count > 0)
         {}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando ya tienes el List en el otro formulario:

```
List<string> polizas = (List<string>)Session["Polizas"];

if (polizas != null && polizas.Any())
{
    // Si quieres un valor especifico del List.
    string variable1 = polizas[0];
    string variable2 = polizas[1];
    // etc...

    // Si quieres recorrer el List y obtener cada valor.
    foreach(string poliza in polizas)
    {
        UnTextBox.Text += poliza + ", ";
    }

    // Si quieres asignarlo a otro grid. Nota: así como tienes el List<string> el otro grid solo debe tener una columna.
    MiOtroGrid.DataSource= polizas;
    MiOtroGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hola Alonso pero no entendi lo que haria el foreach, veo que evaluara todos los que ha seleccionado pero mi pregunta es como seleccionarlas y pasarlas a otro webform

Comment: Perdón, es que no entendí bien el resultado que necesitabas. Aplica lo que te comentaron en la otra respuesta para pasarlo a otro form. Ahora bien, actualizo mi respuesta, para ya sea recorrer el List<string> ó asignarlo a otro grid en ese otro form

Comment: Ah ok ok, ya reviso y te comento! muchas gracas!

Comment: Disculpa @Alonso la ultima pregunta es si hay una forma de colocarlos en unos variables por separado en vez de guardarlos todos en un text o label?

Comment: Yo puse un textbox por indicarte un ejemplo, pero tu puedes guardarlo en una variable. La pregunta es... por qué necesitas cada valor de Lis<string> en diferentes variables? Te pregunto eso, porque si necesitas cada valor del List los puedes obtener así: polizas[indice], donde indice es un numero entero en el cual esta almacenado el valor en el List. De igual forma actualizo mi respuesta con algo similar a lo que quieres.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar una variable [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178581.aspx) y almacenas todas las polizas seleccionadas, ya en el otro formulario recuperas dicha información.

```
    if (test.Count > 0)
    {
      Session["Polizas"] = test;
      Response.Redirect("Formulario2.aspx");
    }
```

En el otro formulario en el evento [Page_Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) lo recuperas.

```
List<string> polizas = Session["Polizas"] as List<string>;
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta ya lo pude hacer pero no logro sacar la informacion ahora desde la List<string>